# US v/s European SOP (Motivation Letter) for Ph.D

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, statement-of-purpose, europe

Is there a difference in the kind of SOP you write for European Ph.D. vacancies/structured programs v/s US grad school? -- in terms of length, type of content to be covered (completely technical v/s story-like), or any peculiar difference?

I am writing Motivation Letter for European Ph.D. admits and I don't know what they are looking for in a Motivation Letter.

(I have already applied 15 vacancies, but, no success. I didn't even get interview calls.)

Comment: The motivation letter may not be the reason you have not had any success.

Comment: I get your point, but, I am trying to rule out every possible reason for rejection. (whatever is in my hands.) ; motivation letter is one of them. I have written US-style SOP, so, I am wondering if that is different from what a European admission committee is looking for.

Comment: If you know any, you could ask some successful past applicants to take a look at their SOP. You might have trouble getting a useful answer here because few people have seen many European and many US applications, and within each group the styles of statements probably differ a lot (as Solar Mike said, it's only a small part of the application).

Comment: If anything, a European letter should be more focused since candidates normally start doctoral studies with more background in field.